# Disk usage claims to be nearly full when 79GB is still available

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

My main hard drive is a 128GB SSD of which the system has 119 available which is normal. However, it is nearly full despite the fact that there is only 79GB of files on it according to windirstat to the point of only having 2-3GB left.

I store most of my media and files on a secondary and tertiary TB drive(s) and I’ve cleared out my temp folders, ran disk cleanup and defrag, checked and checked again and I can’t seem to clear up any more space. There should be around 40GB free on this SSD. What is up?

Comment: You are sure that the 40gb missing is not taken up by System files for windows?

Comment: Not according to windirstat. Windows itself is taking up 25GB.

Comment: Does WinDirStat show hidden files? It's possible something in your %USER%/AppData might be taking up a lot of space.

Comment: How much RAM is in your system?

Comment: Also is the 25GB for windows already calculated in your 79GB usage?

Comment: I have 16GB ram and yes windows is already a part of the 79GB usage

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7fvgJRs.png

Comment: this tool is ugly. Use TreeSizeFree and start it as **admin**: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Answer (score 0):

From http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7

> Windows sets the initial minimum size of the paging file equal to the amount of random access memory (RAM) installed on your computer, and the maximum size equal to three times the amount of RAM installed on your computer.

Your 16GB RAM is taking up (reserving) 16GB of SSD space by default. You will have to decrease or turn off your paging file.

One other thing that would eat your SSD space is the hibernation feature. This can consume upwards of 16GB.

Alter both of these features and see if it helps.

A third thing that can eat up your space, but usually doesn't, is the system restore feature.

---

**Go on an adventure**

1. Enable viewing of your hidden and protected system files
2. Open your C:\ drive
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Manually hunt down the missing space

[image]

Comment: Hibernation is already disabled but I'll check into the page file. WinDirStat says it's taking up 15GB but it might be reserving more.

Comment: It certainly could be, anywhere from 16GB - 48GB by default

Comment: I checked and current reserved memory is 16265MB so I don't think that's the problem. Also my system restore is saved to my storage disks instead of my main one, so it's not that either.

Comment: Sounds like it's almost half the problem, or did Windirstat include the pagefile in it's calculation? I am not intricately familiar with Windirstat

Comment: Page file was included in WinDirStat's calculation.

Comment: Image for clarity http://i.imgur.com/7fvgJRs.png Also showing hidden files was one of the first things I did when I built the computer.

Comment: @Regigigity - WinDirStat isn't able to look into some folder or more importantly a file is growing AFTER WinDirStat has look at it because your using 80GB on the disk alone.  I suspect the page file is increasing.  Hibernation isn't disabled...The file clearly is 11GB.

Answer (score -1):

if you would like an in depth analysis of your hard drives space to even tell you how much space is reserved for hibernation(which is most likely your missing space) and even for recycle bin, you may want to look at this application [SpaceSniffer](http://www.filehippo.com/download_spacesniffer/). It will map each folder for you showing where any space might be used of which you are unaware of so you maybe be able to either delete some unwanted areas or deactivate/modify windows hibernation or other features accordingly(like hdd page file size). Hope it helps

Comment: This is just another tool that the user could use, which he has already used a similar tool, this particular tool you suggest doesn't do anything special.  The user is looking for a explanation not a tool.

Comment: I did mention the 3 causes that it might be (Hdd page file, windows hibernation file or recycle bin reserved space). And i mentioned that this app can just help you pin point which is the culprit, so i did give an explanation as well as provide a tool? how can you downvote me on that?

Comment: I don't find software recommendations helpful considering they are using a tool that does exactly the samething as the tool you suggested.  While you mention the page file and the hibernation file and the recycle bin their current program shows this information.  ( I am basically saying this appears to be a comment more than an answer ).  Considering voting is anonymous its unfair to assume the downvote was issued by me.